# easily manageable css in large angular 2/4/5 Project

Tags: angular, optimization

In Angular whenever i wrote css , i wrote component wise css and some styling in global styles.css but is there any best way which will help me in easily changing css in future. Means i changed at one place and it will be reflected everywhere.

What I found :-

```
In cssPropertiesValues.ts
 export const buttonColor="cyan";

In my AbcComponent.html
<div style="width:200px;height:100px;border:2px solid red;" style.backgroundColor={{buttonColor}}></div>

AbcComponent.ts

import * as cssPropertiesValues from '../Reusables/cssPropertiesValues';

export class AbcComponent{
buttonColor;
 ngOnInit() { 
    this.buttonColor=cssPropertiesValues.buttonColor;
}}
```

But this will add inline css in code.I want external styles to be managed by variables.

Second Question :- Is there any concept of global variables and global Functions in  Angular or similar to that which will make my job easy for managing code.

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve this by converting your angular project to SCSS. You can get more idea [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-with-the-angular-cli).

**1. Creating SCSS project with Angular CLI :**

```
ng new My_New_Project --style=scss
```

If you are changing your existing style in your project

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

**2. Tip 2:**

To avoid passing `--style scss` each time you generate a project, you might want to adjust your default configuration of angular-cli globally, with the 
following command:

```
ng set --global defaults.styleExt scs
```

**A simple example is:**

1. create a file called style constants.scss

`In style-constants.scss`

```
//colors
$clr_nevada: #667878;
$clr_white: #fff;
$clr_shark: #292a2b;
$clr_black_40: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
$clr_mountain_mist: #949090;
$clr_shakespeare: #5cb2d5;
$clr_meteor: #d68019;
```

and then in your styles.scss - import the styles

```
// Styles applied globally. Can import other style files too.
@import '/app-styles/style-constants';
```

And then call the style variable in your styles.scss and in any component stylesheet

```
.ui-dialog.ui-widget .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background: #5cb3d5 !important;
  color: $clr_white;
}
```

Hope it helps